# Rocket thrust washing machine drain hose

Tags: plumbing

Washing machine drain hose discharge pressure has increased, causing the hose to blast out of the drain and flooding the basement.  What would cause the pressure to increase?

Comment: Is it possible that the pressure is still the same as before and that some sort of restriction in the drain line if giving the jet of water from the hose something to push against allowing the host to hoist itself out of the drain?

Comment: Is it possible that the drain hose was previously kinked behind the washer and that you recently moved the washer around some and the kink has been relieved? Note that the washer may even have moved itself around if you had placed an unbalanced load in the tub and then the washer tried to do a high speed spin cycle.

Comment: The drain hose should be secured to the drainage standpipe.  Is it?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to actually answer your question without actually asking more questions (see comments section of original question). But despite that you may want to look into installing a drain hose restraint that helps to keep the hose from jetting its way out of the drain drop pipe. This is often a wire assembly that attaches to the hose and the drain pipe. Some ties a short piece of chain is included.

The restraint device can correct for extra high jet strength coming out of the hose but it will not be able to correct for any possible restriction in the down pipe.